# Best plugin to manage media library?

Tags: media, media-library

I'm finding the media section of WordPress a bit hard to manage with it's paginated pages. Is there any plugin that helps display all the files differently? Like more images on one page and perhaps folders etc?

Comment: You can show more images on a page using the built in media library. Click the "screen options" link in the top right corner and change the number from 20 to whatever you want.